Getting integrity token with Windows API and C++
I am trying to get the integrity token of the current process using Windows API. As far as I understood, the process is as follows:

Get the process handle:

DWORD dwPID = 6084;
HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, dwPID);


Get the token handle:

HANDLE hTok;
if (!OpenProcessToken(hProc, TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE, &hTok)) {
    std::cout << "[+] Error: OpenProcessToken " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
}


Then we need to call GetTokenInformation with NULL specified on the out params, just to get the size of the output data in the last parameter:

if (!GetTokenInformation(hTok, TokenIntegrityLevel, NULL, 0, &dwRetLen)) {
    std::cout << "[+] Normal Error: GetTokenInformation - Just Getting the Size :D" << std::endl;
}


Call GetTokenInformation again, this time in order to retrieve the actual data:

if (!GetTokenInformation(hTok, TokenIntegrityLevel, &dwIntegrity, dwRetLen, &dwRetLen)) {
    std::cout << "[+] Error: GetTokenInformation " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
}


Get the integrity token using GetSidSubAuthority and GetSidSubAuthorityCount:

DWORD label = *GetSidSubAuthority(dwIntegrity->Label.Sid, *GetSidSubAuthorityCount(dwIntegrity->Label.Sid) - 1);

This process may seem pretty straight forward, but for some reason, the call *GetSidSubAuthorityCount(dwIntegrity->Label.Sid) will actually return me the pointer that holds the exact address like dwIntegrity->Label.Sid. It's like, GetSidSubAuthorityCount looks like this:
{
    return argument+1;
}

This is a problem, because *GetSidSubAuthorityCount(dwIntegrity->Label.Sid) - 1) will throw me an exception, that the address that I wass trying to access does not exist.
What may be the problem?

Did you check the SID before calling it?

Did you read the documention? It states If the function fails, the return value is undefined. The function fails if the specified SID structure is not valid or if the index value specified by the nSubAuthority parameter is out of bounds.

if (!GetTokenInformation(hTok, TokenIntegrityLevel, &dwIntegrity, dwRetLen, &dwRetLen)) makes no sense. It says, "&dwIntegrity is a pointer to dwRetLen bytes" but that isn't true.

use PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION instead PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION. TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE you not need here. Call GetTokenInformation again - doo this only once, but in loop. from begin allocate sizeof(TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL) + SECURITY_SID_SIZE(1) for PTOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL
